# Javascript: Looping sound with buttons. Error with boolean

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

#### CSS

```
.btnMusic {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  /* Green */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 50px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}    
.btnMusic:hover {
  background-color: darkgreen;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid black;
}    
#options {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

#### JS

```
var boolean_loop = false;
var sound_highhat = new Audio("sound/sound_highhat.mp3");
var sound_lowhat = new Audio("sound/sound_lowhat.mp3");
var sound_synth = new Audio("sound/sound_synth.mp3");
var sound_beat = new Audio("sound/sound_beat.mp3");

function sound_loop() {
  if (boolean_loop === false) {
    document.getElementById("loopoption").innerHTML = "Loop (Active)";
    boolean_loop = true;
  } else if (boolean_loop === true) {
    document.getElementById("loopoption").innerHTML = "Loop";
    boolean_loop = false;
  }
}

function audiostop() {
  sound_highhat.pause()
  sound_highhat.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_lowhat.pause()
  sound_lowhat.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_synth.pause()
  sound_synth.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_beat.pause()
  sound_beat.currentTime = 0.0;

}

function play_highhat() {
  if (boolean_loop === true) {
    sound_highhat.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();

    }, false);
    sound_highhat.play();
  } else if (boolean_loop === false) {
    sound_highhat.play();
  }
}

function play_lowhat() {
  if (boolean_loop === true) {
    sound_lowhat.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
    sound_lowhat.play();
  } else {
    sound_lowhat.play();
  }
}

function play_synth() {
  if (boolean_loop === true) {
    sound_synth.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
    sound_synth.play();
  } else {
    sound_synth.play();
  }
}

function play_beat() {
  if (boolean_loop === true) {
    sound_beat.addEventListener("ended", function() {
      this.currentTime = 0;
      this.play();
    }, false);
    sound_beat.play();
  } else {
    sound_beat.play();
  }
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="musicboard">
  <button class="btnMusic" onclick="play_highhat()">High Hat</button>
  <button class="btnMusic" onclick="play_lowhat()">Low Hat</button>
  <br>
  <button class="btnMusic" onclick="play_synth()">Synth</button>
  <button class="btnMusic" onclick="play_beat()">Beat</button>
</div>
<div id="options">
  <button id="loopoption" onclick="sound_loop()">Loop</button>
  <button onclick="audiostop()">Stop Music</button>
</div>
```

For a school task i've made a small soundboard with 4 sounds. I also have a button triggering a boolean to loop the sounds. The loop works fine, but whenever i stop all the sounds, if i click a sound that has been looped once before; it will loop again no matter the state of the boolean.

Comment: You're adding an event listener to the `ended` event when `boolean_loop` is `true`. That listener will remain attached to the audio object until you remove it, which your code doesn't do.

Answer (score 1):

When you play a sound with looping option true what your code does is, is adds an event listener if loop condition is true. What you probably want to have is to check for the looping condition inside your listener.

Example of adding listener to one of the buttons.

```
    sound_beat.addEventListener("ended", function() {
     if (boolean_loop === true) {
         this.currentTime = 0;
         this.play();
      }
    }, false);
```

So, your code might look like this:

```
var boolean_loop = false;
var sound_highhat = new Audio("sound/sound_highhat.mp3");
var sound_lowhat = new Audio("sound/sound_lowhat.mp3");
var sound_synth = new Audio("sound/sound_synth.mp3");
var sound_beat = new Audio("sound/sound_beat.mp3");

function aListener = function() {
 if (boolean_loop === true) {
     this.currentTime = 0;
     this.play();
  }
};

// once you add listeners to the audio objects, those listeners stay there until they are removed so every "ended" event will trigger a listener
sound_highhat.addEventListener("ended", aListener, false);
sound_lowhat.addEventListener("ended", aListener, false);
sound_synth.addEventListener("ended", aListener, false);
sound_beat.addEventListener("ended", aListener, false);


function sound_loop() {
  if (boolean_loop === false) {
    document.getElementById("loopoption").innerHTML = "Loop (Active)";
    boolean_loop = true;
  } else if (boolean_loop === true) {
    document.getElementById("loopoption").innerHTML = "Loop";
    boolean_loop = false;
  }
}

function audiostop() {
  sound_highhat.pause()
  sound_highhat.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_lowhat.pause()
  sound_lowhat.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_synth.pause()
  sound_synth.currentTime = 0.0;
  sound_beat.pause()
  sound_beat.currentTime = 0.0;
}

function play_highhat() {
    sound_highhat.play();
}

function play_lowhat() {
    sound_lowhat.play();
}

function play_synth() {
    sound_synth.play();
}

function play_beat() {
    sound_beat.play();
}
```

Comment: I tried to rewrite my code ground up on your concept of having eventlisteners to execute the function checking if the boolean is true and it works now. Thank you for the suggestion